# Error in opening a file in python

Tags: python

Let's consider the below code:

```
fp=open('PR1.txt','r')
ch=fp.readlines()
print "%s" % (' '.join(ch))
print "\n"
fp.close()
```

Above code gives an error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'PR1.txt'
```

But when i am provididng its full location i.e;

```
fp=open('D:/PR1.txt','r')
```

then it is working properly...

IS it necessary to provide full location of file or there is some other way too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not necessary, but you need to be certain you are running your script with the right working directory. Your script working directory is evidently *not* `D:/`.

In practice, it is better to only use relative paths if you are in full control of the working directory. You can get the current working directory with [`os.getcwd()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getcwd) and set it with [`os.chdir()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chdir) but using absolute paths is usually better.

For paths relative to the *current module or script*, use the `__file__` global to produce a directory name:

```
import os.path

here = os.path.dirname(os.path.absolute(__file__))
```

then use `os.path.join()` to make relative paths absolute in reference to `here`.

Comment: `import os` and `print(os.getcwd())` if you're unsure of what directory the script is in. And also, 'os.path.abspath('./')` will expand and help you in many ways :) Dang, you edited before i made my comment!